# check if req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

When I try to send post request and check if it empty it gives error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/api/someapi', (req, res) => {
    let{ text } = req.body;
    text = text.trim()
    if (text == "") {
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            message: "No Text"
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Before you can access `req.body`, you must include a body-parsing middleware, like `router.post('/api/someapi', express.urlencoded({extended:false}), (req, res) => {...})`.

Comment: Besides what @HeikoTheißen suggested you should also validate the input. You can use a validation framework such as express-validator to verify whether the right fields in the body are given. Otherwise you can first compare text to undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you may need a body-parsing middleware such as [`body-parser`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)

Next, before we can destructure `req.body` we need to check that there *is* a `text` property

```
if(!req.body.text){
    console.log("req.body.text is either undefined, null or false!);
}
```

After we know that we **do** have the text property, we can then do additional validation. Try something like this for your purposes:

```
if(!req.body.text || req.body.text.trim() === ""){
    return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: "No Text"
    });
}

//from here onwards, we know that text exists and has a valid value
```

Answer (score 0):

Add optional chaining while calling `.trim()` method

```js
 text = text?.trim()
 if (!text) {
   // ... error logic
 }
```